# Is there a way to turn on Bluetooth using winapi?

Tags: winapi, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to turn on my computer's Bluetooth using the Windows API only. I didn't see any function in `BluetoothApis.h` for this. If you know any way (maybe using the Device API), I would love to hear it!

This is the setting I want to turn on using the Windows API:

[image]

Comment: Is it the thing you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothenablediscovery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555202/enable-bluetooth-programmatically-using-c-net-not-uwp/54562384#54562384

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Win32 API, but it can be done easily via Windows Runtime API [Windows.Devices.Radios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios?view=winrt-18362). The [RadioState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radiostate?view=winrt-18362) enum can be set to `On`, `Off` or `Disabled`.

A UWP example is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/RadioManager).

For Win32 apps it is still possible to access the Windows Runtime API, for example by compiling with VC++ `/ZM` flag ("Consume Windows Runtime Extension") and invoking `Windows::Foundation::Initialize();` on startup, as explained in the Microsoft's blog: [How to access the Windows 10 APIs from C++](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).

Comment: This is not the *"UWP API"*. It's the *"Windows Runtime API"*. UWP is nothing but one client of the Windows Runtime API. It's important to keep the API and platform separate. Otherwise, you'll cause ever more confusion. For example, you don't need any particular compiler options to consume Windows Runtime APIs. `/ZM` is not a compiler option I'm familiar with, and [/ZW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zw-windows-runtime-compilation) is not required, if you're using WRL or C++/WinRT.

Comment: @IInspectable ok thanks. Wasn't aware that one can use C++/WinRT outside UWP. I must admit I can't really keep up with Microsoft nowadays.